# check if link exist with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nokogiri

I would like to know with nokogiri gem if it's possible to know if a link with an anchor and a text exist in a webpage.

```
external_url = http://anydomain.com/anyurl
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(external_url.body)
.
.
```

a link inside of `external_url`:

```
<a href="http://url1.com" >url1</a>
```

I have these data:

```
href = http://url1.com
link_text = url1
```

I need to know with nokogiri (I can not use mechanize gem) if it's possible to know if exist inside of`external_url` a link with `href = http://url1.com` and with a text `url1`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) method for this :

```
require 'open-uri'

external_url = 'http://anydomain.com/anyurl'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(external_url))

href = 'http://url1.com'
link_text = 'url1'

node = doc.at_xpath("//a[@href = '#{href}' and . = '#{link_text}']")
puts "link not found" if node.nil?
```

Comment: it does not works for me. I get node `nil` and the link exist. You can check if you want in this url `http://www.guitar2000.com/2guitarras/page1.html`

Comment: @hyperrjas Do you want to serach by (`link_text` or `href` ) or (`link_text` and `href` ) ? confirm me please.

Comment: Both. I need to know `link_text` and `href`. I mean, if there is a link formed by a given anchor and a given text. thanks!

Comment: @hyperrjas You get - *get node `nil` and the `link` exist*, as I searched it with *and* condition. But looking at your needs, as you commented, I think you should try it witj `or`.

Comment: I'm getting the same wrong result node `nil` with `or . = "#{link_text}...` thanks!

Comment: `Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Invalid expression: //a[@href = http://www.guitar2000.com or . = clases de guitarra]` Thanks

Comment: The code that works for me is `node = doc.at_xpath("//a[@href = '#{href}' and . = '#{link_text}']")` Thanks!